# Configure error for gobject-introspection Python libs not found

Tags: python, gtk, gobject-introspection

I am building gobject-introspection-1.56.1. getting this configure error, headers are found, but libraries are not found, what libraries?
I have already included all LIBS and LDFLAGS from pkg-config

```
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... found
checking for libraries required to link against libpython... not found
configure: error: Python libs not found. Windows requires Python modules to be explicitly linked to libpython.
```

Comment: Apparently you didn't include the required libs. Could you also list all the flags used?

Comment: LDFLAGS='-IC:/msys32/mingw32/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -IC:/msys32/mingw32/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -IC:/msys32/mingw32/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys32/mingw32/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys32/mingw32/include -LC:/msys32/mingw32/lib' 


LIBS='-lgirepository-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl'

Comment: If you add `-lpython` or `-lpythonX.Y` where X is major and Y is minor *Python* versions? (you might have to add its path `-L...`).